# How to make sure the image is allways positioned to the top?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I use UIImage to display my test image with Aspect Fit mode. I want it to be always positioned to the top and fill as much space as it can (see image below).

How to setup constraints, so that the image will be always positioned to the top (without any gap on taller devices)?

Additional info:
I'm using Xcode 7.0.1
Developing for iOS 8 and above.
I'm using auto layout.

I've tried to set " >= 0" to the bottom constraint, so that the bottom gap could get a double height, but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: there is no problem with your constraints but because you use aspectFit...it doesn't give effect what you want in larger devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm adding an image showing how constraints are setup for the view that contains the image, as well for the image inside the view.

If anyone want to look at my experiments in details I've made a public repo via the link below. It includes the storyboard solution branch as well as code solution branche.

https://bitbucket.org/AndrejBB/test-layout

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you programmatically calculate the size of the imageView and set the frame directly. 
Do so in your `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` method of your viewController.

this will do the trick

```
UIImage *image; // yourImage
CGFloat whRatio = image.size.width/image.size.height;
if (whRatio > 1) {
    // there will be borders on top -> adjust your view
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x,
                                 imageView.frame.origin.y,
                                 imageView.frame.size.width,
                                 imageView.frame.size.height / whRatio);
}
```

You might want to think about also adjusting the imageView in case the image is narrow, to prevent white spaces completely.

Comment: Thank you. This pointed me in great direction, therefore +1. However I still couldn't make it work. In the mean time I've found a solution in the storyboard with the addition of one more UIView and then I've put my UIImage inside this UIView. There I was able to set trailing, leading and bottom constraints to be "greater or equal" than 0. In this way it works. I'm gonna write my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the correct constraints. Did you try to set the contentMode to "Scale to fill".
maybe you are using aspectFit

Comment: Yes, I'm using Aspect Fit. It's wtitten in the description. I want to keep the aspect of the image.

Comment: how about aspect fill?